# FOSUserBundle validate email in controller

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.3

I'm trying to validate fields fosuserbundle in the controller.
I'm passing the values ​​from the request without using the form (I'm using the jquery plugin x-editable). So far I have tried this way but it saves me the email even if it is invalid or empty:

```
    $userId = $request->get('pk');
    $value = $request->get('value');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $em->getRepository('AcmeUserBundle:User')->find($userId);
    if (!$user) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Products entity.');
    }
    $user->setEmail($value);

    $validator = $this->container->get('validator');
    $errors = $validator->validate($user, array('profile'));

    if (count($errors) > 0) {
        return new Response(print_r($errors, true), 400);
    }

    $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager')->updateUser($user);       

    return new Response('', 200);
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: the profile validation group for your user entity contains the email constraint ? did you maybe make a mistake by copy/pasting ? ... unable to find products entity? :)

Comment: I'm actually using the validators fosuserbundle because the email field is part of fosuser user entity, the group profile contains the constraint in the email. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FOSUserBundle uses "Profile" as validation group and not lowercase "profile".

Have a look at the validation configuration [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/validation/orm.xml) and [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/validation.xml).

Comment: I had tried it, but if I enter "Profile" or "Registration" gives me "error 500: Internal Server Error"

Comment: well then inspect your symfony / php / webserver error logs for hints what caused the http 500 status code.

Comment: You were right! My rookie mistake!
I do not understand why every time I pass an object to the function `print_r` or `var_dump` crashes the browser and log in I get this error!
`[Thu Aug 08 18:07:31 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 126095361 bytes) in /var/www/acme/src/acme/UserBundle/Controller/AdminController.php on line 98, referer: http://localhost/acme/web/app_dev.php/it/admin/`
For the moment I solved the problem by extracting a loop with the values ​​that I needed and those passing through.

Comment: @cept0 i appreciate feedback like that, thanks! Don't be too hard with Lughino - he could have at least accepted my valid and working answer to this question after he solved his other issues though ;)